# Some user accounts cannot access internet under Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.04

Everything seems to be working fine in first user account, and that user can access the internet. However, in the second account, there is no internet.

The second user has admin privileges as well.

Comment: to clarify- this is on the same hard drive - first user name no probs. Second user has connection permissions under users and groups as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the network-manager (as the user with working network):

```
System -> Administration -> Network
```

Then select your current network connection and make sure that `Available to all users` is checked.

Comment: under system pref "nwork connections" under auto etho auto connect and available to all users are checked. i do not see "network-manager" under admin?

Comment: i found the answer here... http://practicalswitchtoubuntu.blogspot.com/2009/02/restore-missing-network-manager-applet.html for a workaround. there is probably a better way and i will automate it for now Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @ron o: Please answer your own question together with a short explanation of the solution...and then accept that answer.

Comment: 1. Press the combination Alt+F2. This opens the Run Application window.
2. Type in the Run Application text box: nm-applet --sm-disable
3. Click Run.